# How to Shift the focus of the cursor from one row to another

Tags: javascript, richfaces

I have a Barcode scanning screen in my application.
My requirement is,
When the screen loads focus should be set to the input text which scans the barcode,And after scanning  if that barcode  exists then a new row  should be  added and control of the cursor has to be shifted to the new row's input text that scans the barcode.

Adding of new row works fine,But I am not able to shift the control of the cursor to the newly added row

This is what I have done to focus the control as the screen loads

```
<script>
                window.onload = function setFocus() {
                  document.getElementById("mtsTransferForm:grnDetailsRepeatId:0:barCode").focus();
                 };
             </script>
```

where barCode is the Id of the input text. Can anybody suggest me.. What should I do..

Comment: How are you adding the row and rerendering it?

Comment: when the user enters a barcode .Using  <a4j:support> 's onchange event , I call a function which will add a empty row and I am rendering the <rich:panel enclosing this table...

Answer (score 0):

a4j:support has @oncomplete, you can set the focus there:

```
<a4j:support oncomplete="document.getElementById('table:row').focus()" … />
```

The code is executed when the response comes from the server and the table is rerendered.